# Не получается определить счастливое число

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

**Задача:**

Счастливое число — это число, определённое следующим процессом: начиная с любого положительного целого числа, мы заменяем это число суммой квадратов его цифр в десятичной системе счисления и повторяем данный процесс, пока число либо не станет равно 1 (где весь процесс остановится), или попадёт в бесконечный цикл, не содержащий 1. Числа, для которых данный процесс заканчивается единицей, называются счастливыми числами, в то время как те, для которых процесс не заканчивается единицей, считаются несчастливыми числами.

Напишите функцию, которая определяла бы является ли заданное число N счастливым.

**Входные данные:** N - натуральное число от 1 до 1000.

**Вывод:** true/false - является ли число счастливым.

**Примеры**

```
N = 19
1^2 + 9^2 = 82
8^2 + 2^2 = 68
6^2 + 8^2 = 100
1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1.
Output: true
N = 2;
Output: false
```

**Код:**

```
def happy(n):
    numbers = list(map(int, str(n)))
    res = sum([i ** 2 for i in numbers])
    if res == 1:
        return True
    elif len([i for i in numbers if i != 0]) == 1:
        return False
    else:
        happy(res)


print(happy(19))
```

выводит `None`

Хотя в дебагере появлялась 1 и по идее `return` должен сработать. Так почему функция выявляет что сумма квадратов равна 1 и все равно потом лезет в `else`?

Comment: `return happy(res)`. Функции при отсутствии return возвращают None.

Comment: точно)столько времени ковырялся ,а оказалось надо 1 слово дописать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ уже дали в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234657/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE#comment2164756_1234657) ([@godva](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180710/godva)) - вы забыли `return` в блоке `else`.
Я лишь дам несколько советов:

1. Слово `else` можно не писать. Код туда и так не дойдет при выполнении одного из предыдущих условий:

```
def happy(n):
    numbers = list(map(int, str(n)))
    res = sum([i ** 2 for i in numbers])
    if res == 1:
        return True
    elif len([i for i in numbers if i != 0]) == 1:
        return False
    return happy(res)
```

2. В `sum` можно передать генератор, а не список:

```
res = sum(i ** 2 for i in numbers)
```

3. Лучше использовать `i*i` вместо `i**2` (из-за особенностей реалилизации возведения в степень `python` будет быстрее `i*i`)

```
res = sum(i*i for i in numbers)
```

4. В `elif` можно не использовать оператор `!=`:

```
elif len([i for i in numbers if i]) == 1:
   return False
```

5. Еще лучше будет, если сразу отфильтровать `numbers`:

```
numbers = list(filter(bool, map(int, str(n))))
```

ну или так, если не любите `filter`:

```
numbers = [i for i in map(int, str(n)) if i]
```

**Итог**:

```
def happy(n):
    numbers = list(filter(bool, map(int, str(n))))
    res = sum(i*i for i in numbers)
    if res == 1:
        return True
    elif len(numbers) == 1:
        return False
    return happy(res)
```

"Ужатая версия":

```
def happy(n):
    numbers = list(filter(bool, map(int, str(n))))
    res = sum(i*i for i in numbers)
    return True if res==1 else False if len(numbers)==1 else happy(res)
```

Ну и решение без рекурсии:

```
def happy(n):
    while True:
        numbers = list(filter(bool, map(int, str(n))))
        n = sum(i*i for i in numbers)
        if n == 1:
            return True
        if len(numbers)==1:
            return False
```

Comment: `lambda x: x` место этого можно написать `bool`

Comment: @Danis спасибо за подсказку. что-то забыл про нее.

Comment: @n1tr0xs Спасибо  за такой развернутое объяснение,не знал про bool что он так может работать с 0,и про i ** 2,с генератором я так понял память засоряться не будет.Я пытался сделать ответом комментарий,но не нашел такого варианта,только возможность ответить самому на свой вопрос,думал нужно какое то время для выбора ответа